# How to implement draggable pushpin in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

Im placing a customTemplated pushpin on the map(placed dynamically through code behind). The user should be able to relocate it by touch and drag. The new location should also be available.

I have went through the following posts

[draggable pushpin windows phone 7 bing maps control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313890/draggable-pushpin-windows-phone-7-bing-maps-control)

[WP7 dragging a pushpin on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591166/wp7-dragging-a-pushpin-on-a-map)

The answers were unclear or not applicable for WP7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 dragging a pushpin on a map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591166/wp7-dragging-a-pushpin-on-a-map)

Comment: I get it i have mentioned it on the post itself. Could you explain its answer?